# Adding active class to current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I'm looking to add an active element class to my current navbar, but currently struggling.

I've tried the w3schools method, but maybe i've implemented it incorrectly.

**CODE:**

```js
// Get the container element
var btnContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

// Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("link");

// Loop through the buttons and add the active class to the current/clicked button
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  top: 3.5em;
  right: 3.5em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tab:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.link:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .tab:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .text:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">

 <div class="tab">

  <a class="link active" href="#home">
   <div class="text">Home</div>
  </a></div>

 <div class="tab">

  <a class="link" href="#work">
   <div class="text">Work</div>
 </a></div>
 
 <div class="tab">
  
  <a class="link" href="#about">
   <div class="text">About</div>
 </a></div>
</div>
```

The nav bar is currently working but theres no active element. I'd like the tab to be opacity: 1 when active.

Comment: `tab` is not an `id`, it's a class, `getElementById` won't work

Comment: @CalvinNunes i've changed 'getElementById' to 'getElementsByClassName' and still doesn't work - Any ideas?

Comment: "active" do you mean by hovering the element or by clicking it?

Comment: @CalvinNunes I mean by clicking it :)

Comment: Why does the comment say *'Get all buttons with class="btn" inside the container'* but you're getting those with class "link" instead?

Comment: @PeterKA sorry, because it is code from w3schools

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to add the class to the parent div, not the link, since it is the parent who has the opacity set to 0.3. Now, I did it in `jQuery` since it is much easier to achieve. Hope it is not a problem.

```js
$('.link').on('click', function() {
  $('.link').parent().removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  top: 3.5em;
  right: 3.5em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tab:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.link:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .tab:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .text:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">

 <div class="tab active">

  <a class="link" href="#home">
   <div class="text">Home</div>
  </a></div>

 <div class="tab">

  <a class="link" href="#work">
   <div class="text">Work</div>
 </a></div>
 
 <div class="tab">
  
  <a class="link" href="#about">
   <div class="text">About</div>
 </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Alain, I've just tried this method and still no luck, but works when I run it through your code snippet..

Comment: Did you add the jQuery library to your project?

Comment: I did! Not sure why there's an issue

Comment: Weird :(, did you clear the cache from your browser after the changes?

Answer (score 1):

See a quick jQuery solution below using the following methods:

- .on()
- .closest()
- .addClass() and
- .removeClass()

```js
$(function() {
    var links = $('.tab > .link');
    links.on('click', function() {
        links.removeClass('active').closest('.tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active').closest('.tab').addClass('active');
    })
    .first().click();
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  top: 3.5em;
  right: 3.5em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tab:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.link:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .tab:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .text:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">

 <div class="tab">

  <a class="link active" href="#home">
   <div class="text">Home</div>
  </a></div>

 <div class="tab">

  <a class="link" href="#work">
   <div class="text">Work</div>
 </a></div>
 
 <div class="tab">
  
  <a class="link" href="#about">
   <div class="text">About</div>
 </a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Peter, this worked! - The only solution on here that has worked for me as well. However now, it seems to start with no active state, where I want the 'Home' page to start active. The 'Text' also doesn't stay active, only the 'Tab' - Here's a codepen so you understand easier (https://codepen.io/JustNayWillo/pen/aXpKbb) - Thanks!

Comment: To have Home start off active you can add `.first().click()` as shown or simply add `active` class to the first `.tab` element in the html.To make the `Text` active simply make the `.removeClass()` and `addClass()` changes shown.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can use [.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.tab .link').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab.active').forEach(ele => ele.classList.remove('active'));
        ele.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
    });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  top: 3.5em;
  right: 3.5em;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 3.5em;
  width: 0.2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.tab:hover{
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.link:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .tab:hover {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}

.active, .text:hover > .text {
  opacity:1;
  transition:0.7s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="link active" href="#home">
            <div class="text">Home</div>
        </a></div>
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="link" href="#work">
            <div class="text">Work</div>
        </a></div>
    <div class="tab">
        <a class="link" href="#about">
            <div class="text">About</div>
        </a></div>
</div>
```